# Presenting ViewController undesirably visible between transitions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController, HomeVC, who manages the transition between three other view controllers, PhotopickerVC, CroppingVC and EditingVC.

As HomeVC dismisses one VC and presents another VC, I get an undesired effect in which HomeVC is visible for a fraction of a second between these transitions.

Here is a little more details about my code.

The normal flow of the app is HomeVC → PhotopickerVC → CroppingVC → EditingVC (both PhotopickerVC and CroppingVC are only assisting in getting to the final EditingVC, they are no longer required after they are dismissed).

I implement this flow using segues from the HomeVC in the following form:

1. Starting from HomeVC visible, Photo button is pressed, a (subclassed)  `UIImagePickerController` is created and presented.
2. When photo was chosen, (subclassed)  `UIImagePickerController` calls  `[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];` This takes us back to HomeVC
3. In HomeVC method `viewWillAppear`, I call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CroppingVC" sender:self];`
4. In CroppingVC, when user presses Accept button, CroppingVC calls  `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];` This takes us back to HomeVC
5. In HomeVC `viewWillAppear`, I call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"EditingVC" sender:self];`
6. In EditingVC, when the user presses Home, EditingVC calls  `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` This takes us back to HomeVC.

Comment: Please add code, how are you dismissing the HomeVC ?
OR
Present your another view controller when your HomeVC dismisses. You can do this in completion handler of the method,

`[VCObj dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:[Present another VC Here]];`

Comment: does this view controller have a transparent background or a background color with alpha less than 100%?

Comment: If it does have a transparent background or color, put it to not transparent.

Comment: @TusharJ, HomeVC is never dismissed. In your recommendation to present in the completion handler, in that case, who will be the presenter of the newly presented VC?

Comment: So you are saying that, you are dancing three different view controllers on (OR above, because they are presented) HomeVC. And HomeVC is responsible to manage them. So while dismissing oneVC and displaying another VC, you could see HomeVC for fraction of seconds. So whatever behaviour you are getting is appropriate. I would rather say it is recommended to wait to be get dismissed one view controller to present another one. Otherwise you could get warnings like “Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for VCObj”. Suggestion : You could show HUD between this process.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you do not really need the HomeVC to manage transitions. What you should do, is to make the VC hierarchy exactly as you wrote:

HomeVC → PhotopickerVC → CroppingVC → EditingVC

The arrows should be eg. push segues, and then in the prepareForSegue method you can just pass all the necessary parameters.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    YourViewController *destinationController = (YourViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    // do sth
}
```

This way you can achieve nice and smooth transitions. The way your application is now seems to have a structural flaw, because as you have said, when a ViewController gets used once, it is not needed anymore. After that you can just return to the HomeVC.

Comment: Rafal, as I mentioned in my original question, I do not need PhotopickerVC or CropVC again. It would seem wasteful to keep them around.